# Why did my player reset in my friend's Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I first couldn't even join my friend's Minecraft world, but when I was finally able to it had reset my inventory, XP, and everything else associated with my character. Why is this and is there a way I can fix/prevent it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Was this the first time you joined your friend's world because if it is that's completely normal.

Answer (score 2):

Your stuff does not retain when joining new worlds. Your stuff is associated to your account per world.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a multiplayer game-joining lag. This is what usually happens to my friend. Sometimes, when they (not specifying their gender) want to join, all their items seem to be lost. All it takes though is rejoining to regain everything.

Assuming it is not a realm world, but a LAN game, this is something that can randomly occur.